# How to send SSM (Agent) status notification to SNS within AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, aws-ssm

**My question is**

**Is there any other way to monitor the SSM status and send the event notification to SNS** instead of configuring the SNS Topic from the executor by providing `NotificationConfig` ?

I encounter a scenario where within our staging environment, there is an SNS top with a subscription that can always receive the SSM(systems manager) status notification, and it will trigger a lambda function to send notifications to our Slack App. *Was done by our previous colleague*.

However, within our production environment, I can't set up such a topic that can always receive the SSM status notification.

Within the staging, the SSM agent is triggered through a python lambda function. It sends commands with the PowerShell script without configuring the `NotificationConfig` argument. I wonder how this event is sent to the SNS topic.
I follow AWS' documentation which assigns the SNS Topic to the executor of the command. I know this way. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/monitoring-sns-rc-send.html)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture any AWS event using `EventBridge`.
[image]

Comment: To be more specific it is event rule under event bridge. Thanks man

Comment: Could you accept the answare?